# How to activate KafkaBatchListener via application.properties (factory.setBatchListener(true))

Tags: java, spring-kafka

The documentation clearly states how to set the factory settings to enable the batch listener: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#batch-listeners

I do all other configuration via the application properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=url
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=record
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=id-we
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1000
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.meteogroup.kafka.envelope.StringEnvelopeDeserializer
```

I would like to avoid moving all of this manually into the code by @Value parameters. Is there a way to activate batch listening via application properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not via properties, but you can simply override boot's default auto configuration for the factory...

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);

    factory.setBatchListener(true);

    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Shound't we go ahead and expose such a configuration property? Looks like pretty handy feature.

Comment: seems IntelliJ complaints about not existing bean to autowire, but it starts up. This looks quite handy. I have to test this on the right environment.

Comment: These infrastructure beans are not autowired anywhere per se; they are used by the framework to create the listener container(s) for `@KafkaListener` methods. You can add `@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)` but IntelliJ still says "No matching autowire candidates found" (if that's what you are talking about).